Is there a way to fix the add to cart error message in opencart
URL says Not Found Not Found ("success": "Success: You have added <a href="https:V medprimesupplies.comVindex.php?route=productV product&product_id=40"> GE Solar 8000i Machine < va> to your <a href="https:Wmedprimesupplies comVindex.php? route=checkoutVcart">shopping cart«Va
i have not tried anything
